# Garbage when writing logs using kinesis firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I wish to write logs from one aws account to the other. 
Therefore, I've used the manual in the following link: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CrossAccountSubscriptions.html

After that, I've connected a firehose to the kinesis stream and wrote the results to a S3 bucket.

Then, I've used a simple lambda to test it:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('test1')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

However, when reading the information from the bucket all I got is garbage:

```
ã5PÀj√0¸#zL∞÷ZYñoÜ∫°–^b”KÇdK¡?j9
%‰ﬂª
ÈEÏŒéfòπ≤ﬁÖ`éÆ˛ôÀŸsQá˜≤™äM…Vlºn&9*ù†FIi<nÊÒ<—%6óüLo[ã˝πì™ev¶'V¬A«¿cûƒªß∑¢.´zè
LÍ=œ@µ^[.ïB4 —Ú¶%âp∂°ôªiÈ∆·•;ën`˘ém]”Mùñá˛˛nV~Úwø≤Æ%O!9$âTöc•‡4…DHzï R»hWR(ôJï  §]q$ﬂ•£V”S@êäs.4
j`ıﬂ…Wu±≠£≠˚:ıµÕ#+Z´ïI÷ç_£—vm]CkÎ]Ê≥F¯£ä@aÚË—¬Á¿n˚€/πó˘SÜã≠ë_k€0≈øä1Éæ$ı’)o)ÒJaŸFÏ=µ°H∂\∂ìYŒ∫¨ÙªÔ⁄tÉ
ˆ"°sÆŒÔÍÍ%Ì|åˆ…óÁ£OWÈf]Æ∑yQ¨oÛtëû{?†ÃÅ+£    ·Üî€√”Ìp8—…ÏsÃZ€π⁄f(««—«ÔÃE≈8x€ab2–Ï˛›áuôÂû+be”Ä&™Ê§1é/c‹AUcD<πX
·8ÜCˇ>¥ò”’}∫ÛU8ﬂèo˘˚ñCeÚ_“P#ì    î
eÄS&î`ö )@sJS∏sB©•àîRÇÜr«ÄSmá$B3úq
ã_”¬xw5Ωî,›˜´á>}]¸∆ÀôÑI™5 4#\)t@(…ïPääi!í¸lƒ%8ˇ∏Iv˛Î    ÔÍU‚XÌå≤tÈπmñ‹∑tæ¬c›x›Ëä5íˇáÓË_v∑À?⁄ïˇ‹‡∏9
v˙ÊUBƒµ§I∆õ–∂æN.,ÄŸÿ˙Ó0úì"¸(RùloP¥ﬂì7„KÙb÷Ô˙0^f~-’3çeˇ˙ÀÂ,Ü
```

Any idea what should I do in order to have a human-readable file?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: It's probably the compressed format.

Comment: yes, this was the issue. Thanks kichik!